# Create a new column based on several conditions

Tags: r, data-manipulation, recode

I want to create a new column based on some conditions imposed on several columns. For example, here is an example dataset:

```
a <- data.frame(x=c(1,0,1,0,0), y=c(0,0,0,0,0), z=c(1,1,0,0,0))
a
  x y z
1 1 0 1
2 0 0 1
3 1 0 0
4 0 0 0
5 0 0 0
```

Specifically, if for any particular row 1 is present, then the new column returns 1. If all are 0, then the new column returns 0. So the dataset with the new column will be

```
  x y z w
1 1 0 1 1
2 0 0 1 1
3 1 0 0 1
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
```

My initial thought was to use `%in%` but couldn't get the result I want. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `max` of each row :

```
a$w <- do.call(pmax, a)
a

#  x y z w
#1 1 0 1 1
#2 0 0 1 1
#3 1 0 0 1
#4 0 0 0 0
#5 0 0 0 0
```

which can also be done with `apply` :

```
a$w <- apply(a, 1, max)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame consists of binary values, e.g., only `0` and `1`, you can try the code below with `rowSums`

```
a$w <- +(rowSums(a)>0)
```

such that

```
> a
  x y z w
1 1 0 1 1
2 0 0 1 1
3 1 0 0 1
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Elegant! Thank you! Just curious, what if the data are not binary? For example, if a row contains values just from 1 to 5, recode the value to 1, and if it contains any other values, recode to 2.

Comment: @cliu Then you can try `2-(a >= 1) * (a <= 5)` for recoding

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowMaxs` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
a$w <- rowMaxs(as.matrix(a))
a$w
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0
```